# TLSv1.x and javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException with POP3 protocol

Tags: java, sockets, email, tls1.2, java-ee-7

I have to read some emails in inbox from an email account. I need the TLSv1.2 like system update and when I send an email I can correctly do this but this methodology does not work when I have to read from the inbox folder.
Following my java code about connection preparation:

```
     props.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
     props.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port", Integer.valueOf(extProperties.getPortInbox().trim()));
     props.put("mail.pop3.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
     props.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", Boolean.TRUE);
     props.put("mail.pop3.ssl.enable", Boolean.FALSE);
     props.put("mail.mime.multipart.ignoreexistingboundaryparameter", Boolean.TRUE);
     props.put("mail.mime.parameters.strict", Boolean.FALSE);
```

the params that I have are:

```
Protocol Type: POP3
Inbox server: (my server url)
Port: 995
```

I have this errors when I try to connect and read from the inbox folder:

```
...
(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1) SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1, received EOFException: error
(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1) SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1) SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1) SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1) SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1, called closeSocket()
...
```

In the log above, we can see the handshake error and the tlsv1 instead of the tlsv1.2 that I have setted.
How can I solve my problem? I have tried many ways found on stakoverflow/internet but I didn't resolve my problem and now I have no idea about the next step to do.

Thank you for the help

Comment: The server has closed the connection during TLS handshake. Unfortunately this can be lots of things, like some DPI firewall intercepting the traffic, server too old, java too old, no POP3 server running on this port, server misconfiguration ... First things you should check is if it works with a different application.

Comment: You can try to set a lower requested protocol level "TLSv1" or "TLSv1.1". Also you can try to activate SSL debug by setting system property javax.net.debug=all to get more information on what's going wrong.

Comment: @Stefan D. if I use a different version of TLS, that can be a problem? For example, if I use TLSv1 but the email server use TLSv1.2 this difference can be a problem?

Comment: @Pipo: Yes of course. If the server requests a higher ptotocol level than the client could offer there is no way for a connection. Same applies vice versa. Default behavior is to request the highest possible level i.e. TLSv1.2 with an option to fall back to a minnimum level i.e. TLSv1. But this fallback can be disabled and a desired level can be configured. As said before, try to debug the connection. Help to analyze the output can be found in this Oracle document https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html and RFC 2246 and followers.